# When I include a class such as <vector> and only use 1 or 2 of its member functions, what does the compiler do?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a program like the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> V; 
   V.push_back(69);
   std::cout << *V.begin();
   return 0;
}
```

I've only used 2 functions from the `vector` class, meaning there is a lot of things unused from that gigantic class. Does my compiler somehow create a `vector` object that has been stripped of a ton of its functions??? Or does my compiler think, "*Oh, all he's doing is printing an integer, so I don't even need to import the `vector` class*." I want to understand what happens on a machine level when I write the above code.

Comment: Objects don't include functions anyway; the class itself does. Anyway, you can check what happens by viewing the generated assembly.

Comment: The exact amount of code included by this will depend on the exact implementation of `vector`. Indeed, there might be some `vector` code in the final program even if the program doesn't even include `vector` (if there's some type-independent part of the code in the C++ runtime lined to the program).

Comment: @celtschk any type-independent code would need to be outside the class itself, correct? Either as a base class or standalone functions. I know Microsoft's versions of `set` and `map` work this way.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It would have to be outside of the class template, yes. But that wouldn't change the fact that it still is part of the implementation of `vector`.

Comment: @celtschk: Any C++ header might include and use `<vector>` for its own reasons. I could certainly imagine `<string>` doing so. That means you can't reliably predict which methods will be used.

Answer (score 1):

`vector` is a *template* class, which means it's just a guide to generate the code when it's needed after you've provided the necessary parameters. If it's not needed, it's not generated.

Comment: However the implementation of `vector` may make use of type-independent code which is not templated.

Comment: @celtschk even so it would still be considered inline.

Comment: Not necessarily. A compiler writer could well decide e.g. that some of that type-independent code should be in the standard runtime linked to every program.

Comment: Tue, but unlikely for a class as simple as `vector`. Its members are either type-dependent, allocator-dependent, or (size/capacity) so simple that they are certainly inlined.

Answer (score 1):

None of this is STRICTLY defined by the C++ standard. The standard makes allowances for optimisation by a simple concept called "as-if" - the code should behave "as-if" the compiler had produced the code written. In this case, it's entirely possible that the whole thing turns into a call to `operator<<(cout, 69);`. I expect something fairly close to this to be done my a compiler with -O2 or -O3.

Equally, the compiler could produce all the required code for creating the vector `V` (in other words, the constructor for the class and any member functions being called by the the code), adding the element to the back of the vector with a content of `69`, creating a temporary `std::vector<int>::iterator` object, dereferencing that temporary object to get the `69` back out, and passing that to `operator<<` along with the `cout` stream. This is what I'd expect with a -O0 (no optimisation) option.

Or something in between those two options.

Edit: Having looked at the code generated by g++ (4.8.2) and clang (3.5 branch as of 16th of April). Both remove most of the "vector generation", but does in one way or another construct some parts of the iterator, and then passes the value from there into the `operator<<`.

The mechanism is largely based on templates (again, this is not strictly defined by the standard - it just defines the overall definition of `std::vector` as a template class - exactly how that is then implemented depends on the compiler/library producer - as long as the behaviour is that what is described by the C++ standard), which are typically declared in header files, and as such, the source-code for the implementation is completely available to the compiler, and the compiler can remove large swathes of code simply because it's "not used".

With no optimisation, using clang++, we get this LLVM-IR code:

```
define i32 @main() #2 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %V = alloca %"class.std::vector", align 8
  %ref.tmp = alloca i32, align 4
  %exn.slot = alloca i8*
  %ehselector.slot = alloca i32
  %coerce = alloca %"class.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator", align 8
  %cleanup.dest.slot = alloca i32
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  call void @_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEEC2Ev(%"class.std::vector"* %V)
  store i32 69, i32* %ref.tmp
  invoke void @_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE9push_backERKi(%"class.std::vector"* %V, i32* %ref.tmp)
          to label %invoke.cont unwind label %lpad

invoke.cont:                                      ; preds = %entry
  %call = invoke i32* @_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE5beginEv(%"class.std::vector"* %V)
          to label %invoke.cont1 unwind label %lpad

invoke.cont1:                                     ; preds = %invoke.cont
  %coerce.dive = getelementptr %"class.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator"* %coerce, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32* %call, i32** %coerce.dive
  %call3 = invoke i32* @_ZNK9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEdeEv(%"class.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator"* %coerce)
          to label %invoke.cont2 unwind label %lpad

invoke.cont2:                                     ; preds = %invoke.cont1
  %0 = load i32* %call3
  %call5 = invoke %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEi(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZSt4cout, i32 %0)
          to label %invoke.cont4 unwind label %lpad

invoke.cont4:                                     ; preds = %invoke.cont2
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  store i32 1, i32* %cleanup.dest.slot
  call void @_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEED2Ev(%"class.std::vector"* %V)
  %1 = load i32* %retval
  ret i32 %1

lpad:                                             ; preds = %invoke.cont2, 
 ... exception handling removed ... 
}
```

This is the result using -O2:

```
define i32 @main() #2 {
if.else.i:
  %V = alloca %"class.std::vector", align 8
  %ref.tmp = alloca i32, align 4
  %0 = bitcast %"class.std::vector"* %V to i8*
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* %0, i8 0, i64 24, i32 8, i1 false) #1
  store i32 69, i32* %ref.tmp, align 4, !tbaa !1
  invoke void @_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi(%"class.std::vector"* %V, i32* null, i32* %ref.tmp)
          to label %invoke.cont1 unwind label %lpad

invoke.cont1:                                     ; preds = %if.else.i
  %_M_start.i.phi.trans.insert = getelementptr inbounds %"class.std::vector"* %V, i64 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0
  %.pre = load i32** %_M_start.i.phi.trans.insert, align 8, !tbaa !5
  %1 = load i32* %.pre, align 4, !tbaa !1
  %call5 = invoke %"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZNSolsEi(%"class.std::basic_ostream"* @_ZSt4cout, i32 %1)
          to label %invoke.cont4 unwind label %lpad

invoke.cont4:                                     ; preds = %invoke.cont1
  %tobool.i.i.i9 = icmp eq i32* %.pre, null
  br i1 %tobool.i.i.i9, label %_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEED2Ev.exit11, label %if.then.i.i.i10

if.then.i.i.i10:                                  ; preds = %invoke.cont4
  %2 = bitcast i32* %.pre to i8*
  tail call void @_ZdlPv(i8* %2) #1
  br label %_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEED2Ev.exit11

_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEED2Ev.exit11:                  ; preds = %invoke.cont4, %if.then.i.i.i10
  ret i32 0

lpad:                                             ; preds = %if.else.i, %invoke.cont1
 ... exception handling removed...
}
```

Comment: Did I say that? I guess you could imply that from something I said, but I sure didn't mean it...

Comment: I added some text to (attempt to) clarify.